# Defining static files just before rendering in Express.js

Tags: node.js, express

I want to define static css and js folder in my express app before rendering. I can't make it in my app.js file this way:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public', subfolder)));
```

because subfolder value depends on request. Is there any other way to define it in controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you need, in this case we use Express's sendFile for each request:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

app.get('/:path/*', function(req, res) {
    // You could also use query string parameters for this, e.g. req.query.param1
    let filePath = path.join(req.params.path, req.params[0]);
    console.log('Getting ' + filePath);
    res.sendFile(filePath, {root: './'});
});

app.listen(8081);
```

If, for example you have the folders /path1 and /path2, both containing test.html, the requests:

```
http://localhost:8081/path1/test.html
```

and

```
http://localhost:8081/path2/test.html
```

Will bring you to the relevant file. You can also use query parameters rather than path parameters to decide which directory to serve.

In this case you might form the path like so:

```
let filePath = path.join(req.query.myVariable, req.params[0]);
```

The full server would then be:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    let filePath = path.join(req.query.path, req.params[0]);
    console.log('Getting ' + filePath);
    res.sendFile(filePath, {root: './'});
});

app.listen(8081);
```

And the relevant Urls would be:

```
http://localhost:8081/test.html?path=path1
```

and

```
http://localhost:8081/test.html?path=path2
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: Great to hear! You might accept the answer if it works :) Thanks.